# Liquibase: Incorrect syntax near ;

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, liquibase

I am trying to deploy db changes using Liquibase and getting the below error on one of the stored procedure code.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON: Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:104)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.execute(AbstractDatabase.java:1075)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractDatabase.java:1059)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:317)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:649)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$1ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:92)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
```

The sp looks like:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP] 
    AS
    BEGIN

        SET NOCOUNT ON;


        SELECT Col1, Col2
        FROM dbo.[Table1] 

    END
    GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[testsp] TO [SomeRole]
GO
```

And the changeset looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog          http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

  <changeSet id="6a07201a-133e-4613-b4cf-15becbf53baf" author="Nadeem">

    <sqlFile path="./Creation Scripts/Stored Procedures/testsp.sql" />
    <rollback>
      <sqlFile path="./Update Scripts/Stored Procedures/testsp.Rollback.sql" />
    </rollback>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Remove the ;. I don't think MSSql accepts that.

Comment: I am using SQL Server and the sp code executes successfully if I run that directly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you use the [`<sql>`](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql) or [`<sqlFile>`](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql_file)refactoring tag. They automatically split your queries on `;` and `GO`. That's not what you want in this case.

You can either set the attribute `splitStatements` to `false` or use the [`<createProcedure>`](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/create_stored_procedure) refactoring tag instead.

Comment: I am using SqlFile and the script of the the sp is in a .sql file. I have edited the question to add the changeset.

Comment: I tried <sqlFile path="./Creation Scripts/Stored Procedures/testsp.sql" splitStatements="false"/>. But this doesn't work

Comment: Ataully after setting the SplitStatments to false I am getting 'INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR GO' on the last GO

Comment: Try <sqlFile path="..." endDelimiter="GO" />

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just a missed brackets from the select query:

**(select permission_id from aro_permission where permission_name='edit data')**

```
<changeSet dbms="mssql" author="prashant" id="AP-11120.1">
    <insert tableName="RESOURCE_PERMISSION">
        <column name="ID"
            valueNumeric="${nextval_start}RESOURCE_PERMISSION_SEQ${nextval_end}" />
        <column name="PERMISSION_ID"
            valueComputed="(select permission_id from permission where permission_name='flow')" />
        <column name="RESOURCE_TYPE" value="workflow" />
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```